# How to find the integration of the given expression

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How to solve Integration of

$$\int \dfrac{\sqrt{x^2 +1}}{x+1}$$

I tried putting $x=2\tan t$. But not getting the final solution

Comment: Welcome to Math. SE. In your posts here, when necessary, always use $\LaTeX$.

Comment: Isn't $x=\sinh(t)$ the standard substitution in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Substitute  $x=\tan t$ to integrate

\begin{align}
& \int \frac{\sqrt{x^2 +1}}{x+1}dx\\
=&\int \frac{\sec^3t}{\tan t+1}dt =\int \frac{(\tan t -1)(\tan t+1)+2}{\tan t+1}\sec tdt  \\
= &\int \left( \tan t\sec t -\sec t + \sqrt2 \sec(t-\frac\pi4) \right)dt\\
=&\sec t -\ln(\sec t+\tan t) + \sqrt2\ln(\sec(t-\frac\pi4)  +\tan(t-\frac\pi4) )+C
\end{align}